# How to prevent Unity from triangulating faces of imported models?

Tags: unity, models

I have an object that will be rendered with a wireframe shader. This means that line between vertices in a model would be drawn.

The problem is that Unity automatically triangulates all n-gons in my models. I want these n-gons to render as is.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity supports the following [MeshTopology](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshTopology.Triangles.html) types:

- Triangles
- Quads
- Lines
- LineStrip
- Points

It does not, at the time of writing this answer, support topologies with 5 or more points per polygon.

To render a wireframe mesh containing pentagons or more complicated polygons, you can either...

- Render it as a collection of lines using `MeshTopology.Lines` / `LineStrip`.
- Render it as a solid surface, and use a suitable fragment shader to draw lines only along selected edges. (See other questions about drawing wireframe meshes for tips)

Answer (score -1):

When you select your model, on the right hand side you can select an option that says "Keep Quads"
[image]

Comment: Does not seem to work with n-gons for me